# Targetting SDCard vs Phone Storage

Tags: external-sd, internal-storage, sd-card, app2sd, internal-sd

I bought a new phone. It runs JellyBean 4.1.1. It has got 2.5GB Phone storage and Internal Storage of 512 MB. Thats what I find when I go to Manage Apps section of the settings. I can move apps installed in Internal Storage to the Phone Storage. Thats the option I get when I open detail section of any app in Manage Apps.

My previous phone had no phone storage but just the internal storage. In it, when I open up Manage Apps section I use to get the option to "Move app to **SD card**". However now am not able to get option to move the app to SD card but just to the Phone Storage (from Internal Storage). How can I move apps to SD Card instead of to Phone Storage from Internal storage.

When I used ES file explorer I realized the phone storage is recognized as `sdcard` and my SD card is recognized as `sdcard1`.

Also there are some apps that look for the supporting files in their corresponding folder inside sdcard, i.e. at `sdcard\appfolder`. Now since they currently look at `**sdcard0**\appfolder` (i.e. phone storage), I have limitations of not putting bigger files which quickly fills up the phone storage. In my previous phone I created appfolder in my sdcard and pasted those supporting files in those folders and the corresponding apps automatically detected those files. This was convenient since I have 32 GB SDcard. However now I have to create appfolders in phone storage.

Also now many apps by default limits browsing files in phone storage detecting it as a `sdcard`. For example when I open any folder in dropbox and tap Upload Here it directly browse `sdcard`.

Please help.

Comment: You might also wish to take a look into the [app2sd tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info) on our site :)

Comment: Hey thanks but I have tried `app2sd` also. And as far as I understand when it comes to moving apps, `app2sd` also opens the same `Manage Apps` windows with `Move app to phone storage` option

Comment: Again: You might want to take a look at that tag-wiki (not just guess by its name :). If you do, you will see why I recommend that: It also mentions (and shortly introduces) alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this: [AndroidForums](http://androidforums.com/android-lounge/715792-whats-difference-between-internal-storage-phone-storage.html#post5785718). The directory structure has been restructured in Jelly Bean. The internal memory resides at /data/media/0, hence the sdcard0 name. SD cards are now known as external SD cards and get the name sdcard1 since Android 4.1. If you want to move apps to your external SD card, I'm afraid you'll have to root. If you do decide to root however, [FolderMount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devasque.fmount) and [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD) work really well.

Comment: No other way to move apps to external sdcard without rooting at all? You sure?

Comment: Yeah, AFAIK, yes. I'm sure of it.